# Как узнать точную дату регистрации андроид разработчиком?

Tags: android, google-play-console

искал в консоли разработчика не смог найти

Comment: Не думаю что такая информация где либо хранится, только если вы сами не распечатывали договор. Зачем это вам?

Comment: хочу указать этот период как самозанятый

Comment: имейл же пришел наверное в тот день

Comment: этого не помню, но вроде сразу приходит, придется этот день указать

Comment: пожалуйста, отпишитесь потом здесь, как прошел процесс! очень хороший лайфхак!)

Comment: написал в ответе

Answer (score 2):

В коносли в Activity Log, чтоб ее найти надо указать дату, так как там показаны логи по фильтрам только последний месяц или последний год, то нужно вручную выставлять даты, т.е. если прошло больше года надо выставить фильтр, причем сама запись будет в самом низу списка.
В моем случае нашел письмо на почте с оплатой аккаунта разраба, выставил примерные фильтры и нашел, день оплаты был тот что и запись в логе.